# ¿Cómo asignarle más recursos a un docker container?

Tags: docker

Cuando uno crea un `docker container` no hay forma de asignarle recursos como `RAM`, `disco duro`, etc. Lo único que he visto es cómo abrir puertos para que haya comunicación con el exterior ([ver acá](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)) y también el cómo agregarle volúmenes ([ver acá](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/)) para almacenar o leer archivos.

Pero no he encontrado una forma de gestionar los recursos de un `docker container`, ¿alguien sabe si es eso posible? ¿hay valores por defecto? ¿crecen automáticamente dependiendo de la demanda? ¿se pueden restringir?

He buscado en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.docker.com/) pero no he encontrado nada relacionado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la referencia para `run` que [esta aqui](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/). En respuesta directa copiando los ejemplos en la documentación:

## Asignar RAM (memoria)

Con limite para memoria hasta 300MB y sin swap

```
$ docker run -ti -m 300M --memory-swap -1 ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Con limite de memoria y con todo el swap que este disponible:

```
$ docker run -ti -m 300M ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Hay una multitud de otras opciones en la documentación (limitar swap, etc). Mira la [referencia](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) que di arriba.

## Asignar disco duro

Desde version 1.9.1. es posible limitar el uso de disco duro de forma directa (en respuesta al incidente [#3804](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3804) donde encontraras la historia de esta funcionalidad). No lo he usado yo mismo, pero [segun la documentación](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/run.md#set-storage-driver-options-per-container) tendria la siguiente forma:

```
$ docker create -it --storage-opt size=120G ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
[...responde con un guid del nuevo contenedor ..
$ docker start -a -i [.. aqui el guid de arriba ..]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Pero no he encontrado una forma de gestionar los recursos de un docker container, ¿alguien sabe si es eso posible?

Si es posible, puedes gestionarlo de las siguientes formas:

**1)** Si estás utilizando la versión más reciente de docker para windows (docker-for-windows) o para Mac (docker-for-mac) puedes localizar el icono de ballena (característico de docker) en la barra de tareas, click derecho sobre el icono y seleccionas configuración. Una vez realizado esto saldrá la interfaz para asignar recursos a la aplicación.

**2)** Puedes utilizar el comando de docker para asignar recursos de la siguiente forma:

**2.1)** Por el nombre del container:

```
docker update --memory "2g" --cpuset-cpu "2" <ballena>
```

**Descripción:** En el comando anterior le estamos asignando 2 Gigas de memoria RAM y 2 núcleos al contenedor "ballena". Dentro de los "<>" se coloca el nombre del contenedor que se puede observar a través del comando `docker ps`. Se debe colocar el nombre sin los símbolos "<>" ya que sólo están allí para referenciar donde se coloca el nombre.

**2.2)** Por el "id" del container:

```
docker update --memory "1g" --cpuset-cpu "4" <0dca4f7e27a6>
```

**Descripción:** de forma similar a 2.1) se asigna 1 Giga de ram y 4 núcleos al contenedor de id "0dca4f7e27a6" por ejemplo. Tomar en cuenta que los símbolos de "<>" tampoco deben ir a la hora de ejecutar el comando.

**3)** Si estás ejecutando docker a través de virtual box (versiones anteriores a docker-for-windows) por ejemplo la "Docker Toolbox" puedes reasignar los recursos a través de la opción de configuración ofrecida por la misma maquina virtual.

**Nota:** El proceso también se puede realizar para aquellos usuarios que utilicen VMware con docker (driver de VMware).

**4)** Si por ejemplo utilizas Virtualbox y deseas asignar recursos por comandos puedes intentar:

```
docker-machine stop // Detienes la ejecución de docker
VBoxManage modifyvm ballena --cpus 1 // Asignas 1 núcleo 
VBoxManage modifyvm ballena --memory 2048 // Asignas 2 Gb de RAM 
docker-machine start // Inicias nuevamente docker
```

**Nota:** Los cambios se ejecutarán en "ballena"

> ¿hay valores por defecto? ¿crecen automáticamente dependiendo de la demanda? ¿se pueden restringir?

El mínimo valor "por defecto" para memoria RAM es de 4m (4 megabyte), si se asigna un valor fijo (por ejemplo 3Gb) docker se ajustará al valor tope y si no es asignado ningún valor el consumo de RAM irá incrementando conforme el contenedor requiera más recursos. De igual forma sucede con todos los demás recursos como la cantidad de núcleos por ejemplo. Para más información sobre los valores por defecto y sus límites puedes visitar [documentación oficial de docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu)

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!